# Call GoogleMap MarkerClusterer method from typescript-based angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, typescript, markerclusterer

I've started to investigate TypeScript approach in my project and currently bit confused how to correctly organize the call to MarkerClusterer method. I currently have to type-definitions references:

```
///<reference path="../../typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts" /> 
///<reference path="../../typings/google.maps.d.ts" />
```

But for MarkerClusterer js I was unable to find definition ts library. My code now looks so:

```
class paspController {

public map: any;
public markers;
public mapTab: boolean;
public currentId: number;

//Some code

showTab(tabIndex: number) {
    if (tabIndex == 2) {
        this.mapTab = true;
        var that = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            this.options = {
                zoom: 2,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(1, 1),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            if (!that.map) {
                that.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), this.options);
            }
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'GetDivesWithCoordinates/' + that.currentId,
                success: function (data) {                      
                    that.markers = [];
                    var marker;                       
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        marker = new google.maps.Marker({ map: that.map, draggable: false, title: data[i].Location + ": " + data[i].DiveComment, position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].CoordinateX, data[i].CoordinateY) });
                        that.markers.push(marker);
                    }
                   // THIS IS MY PROBLEM => var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(that.map, markers);
                },
                error: function (e) {
                },
                async: false
            });
        }, 100);           
    }
}
```

How should I correctly call the MarkerClusterer, or maybe I should put it outside the controller logic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> THIS IS MY PROBLEM => var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(that.map, markers);

Declare it :

```
declare var MarkerClusterer:any;
```

And typescript will not complain anymore.

More : http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/migrating.html

Comment: Yep, thanks, fixing scope context did resolved the issue))

Comment: where did you put all this "declare var MarkerClusterer:any;" line? It can go inside the method or class?

Answer (score 1):

Use the below npm package instead of adding scripts directly in angular.

Add this package to your node_modules

```
npm i @googlemaps/markerclustererplus
```

In your Ts file import this:

```
import MarkerClusterer from '@googlemaps/markerclustererplus';

const markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
```

Reference: https://github.com/googlemaps/js-markerclustererplus

Answer (score 0):

I put it after the:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

declare var MarkerClusterer: any;
```

and before

```
@Component({
```